# How to get the last element of a list and return nil if the element isn't in the list

Tags: clisp

I would like to get the position of any element in the list and get nil if the element isn't in the list. I did:

```
(defun myposition (letter list)
  (cond
    ((atom list) nil)
    ((equal (car list) letter) 0)
    ((null (car list)) (myposition letter))
    (t (1+ (myposition letter (cdr list)))) ) )

(myposition 'k '(g h i j k l)
4
(myposition 'p '(g h i j k l)
nil is not a number
```

When I replace `((atom list) nil)` par `((atom list) 0)`, I get 6 instead nil

```
(myposition 'p '(g h i j k l)
6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, your function will recursively compute `1+1+1+1+0 = 4` to find the correct result.

In your second example, it will run through the whole list, add 1 per (non-matching) element, and finally **add** `nil`. So it actually computes `1+1+1+1+1+1+nil`, which is incorrect since `nil` is not a number, hence the error message. If you replace `nil` by zero, it computes `1+1+1+1+1+1+0` which is wrong.

So your basic problem is that you recursively add `1` and, reaching the end of the list, you would like to throw away what you computed until then. But you have an addition pending which you cannot escape.

The easiest way is to change from a recursive to a tail-recursive solution, which is technically a plain `goto`. Here the addition is done by incrementing a variable, not by unwinding the call stack, which makes it easy to throw away the result from the previous additions and just return `nil` because there is no addition pending.

A (tail-)recursive solution could be:

```lisp
(defun myposition (letter lst)
  (labels ((sub (lst pos)
             (cond
              ((null lst) nil)
              ((equal (car lst) letter) pos)
              (t (sub (cdr lst) (1+ pos))))))
    (if (atom lst) nil (sub lst 0))))
```

This will work in Common Lisp, but technically, if your implementation does no [tail call optimisation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), it might still blow the stack for large lists. That's why Common Lisp prefers iterative solutions, such as using the `loop` macro:

```lisp
(defun myposition (letter lst)
  (when (consp lst)
    (loop for c in lst for i from 0
      when (equal c letter) return i)))
```

Comment: You are very smart uselpa. I thank you so much. But I would be more thankful if you help me to find out what hinder me to get nil instead 6. I reckon on your experience.

Comment: I forgot to tell you that your functions work very well and thank for having answered quickly.

Comment: My function works, but the only problem is to find nil when the element isn't in the list.

Comment: @user3653521 Sorry for my sloppy answer. I added an explanation as you requested, don't hesitate to ask for further details if necessary.

Comment: Thank you uselpa for your explanation. your analyse is perfect and reveals the real problem. I have to put a condition before the last one that prevent the implementation go get nil or to stop at the last element in the list. My challenge is to find this line condition. Thank you uselpa for interesting to my case.

Comment: @user3653521  You're welcome. If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: I never know I should check "accepting answer. It is very useful.